# Using the media uploader in a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, widgets, media, oop

As part as a widget I'm creating, I need the admin to upload an image via the widgets panel
I have the following code under a new class

```
<?php
function form($instance) {
   $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'qrimage'=> '');
   $qrimage=$instance['qrimage']; ?>

<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>">
      Upload QR Image:
<input class="wide" 
       id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>" 
       name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>" 
       type="text" 
       value='<?php echo attribute_escape($qrimage); ?>' />
Upload Image 
<label for="uploadi<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>"> 
   <input class="uploadi<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>" 
          name="uploadi<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>" 
          id="uploadi<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>" 
          value="Upload Image" type="button" />
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var formfield = '';
      var imgurl ='';
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.uploadi<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage');?>').click(function() {
         formfield = jQuery('#<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>').attr('name');
         tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp&TB_iframe=1');
         return false;
        });

        // send url back to plugin editor
        window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
         imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
         jQuery('#<?php echo $this->get_field_id('qrimage'); ?>').val(imgurl);
         tb_remove();
        }

        });
  </script>
```

Thing is... if I have 1 instance of the widget on the widgets panel , everything works fine.

Once I add another instance, everything's working on the first instance but on the second one I cannot save the image , The text field gets the value but on save it just disappears

Any thoughts why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The output code of widget's `form` method is added to page once for every instance of the widget (included the "dummy" instance contained in the "Available widgets" panel), so in your case the javascript code that defines the `window.send_to_editor` function may appear more than once, and the last instance overwrites the previous ones.
There are at least two reasons for not output javascript code by the `form` method:

1. When you create a new instance of a widget (with drag & drop), the html code of the "dummy" (marked with `__i__` index) is copied to the newly created widget and the index is replaced with a number, but the event handlers are not copied, so the new widget may not behave as expected.
2. When you save a widget, the data is sent via ajax to the server and the output of the `form` method is sent back to the page and then added to the DOM dynamically. According to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#data-types), "any embedded JavaScript inside the retrieved data is executed before the HTML is returned as a string", and this may lead to odd behaviors (moreover not all browsers behave the same way about this).

I recommend you to put your javascript code in a separate js file, and include in the page head by using [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and use the jQuery [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to add event handlers. You may use a generic event handler for all instances and then look for the proper DOM elements to apply the relevant actions. Example:

```
jQuery('input[id^=uploadi]').live('click', function() {
     formfield = jQuery('input[id^=qrimage]', jQuery(this).closest('.widget')).attr('name');
     tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=1');
     return false;
});
```

Note: change `qrimage` selector in the above code (not tested) to whatewer your field prefix is.

P.s. I also noticed a typo in the url `media-upload.php?type=image&amp&TB_iframe=1`